# How to tell if a proof relativizes?

Tags: oracle-machines, relativization

If I have a proof for a separation between two complexity classes (using no oracles) and I want to see if it relativizes, how do I go about doing so?

Especially in the case where there already exist proofs for these classes being equal with respect to one oracle and not equal with respect to another oracle. I'm wondering, if I have a proof of inequality with respect to no oracle can I simply reference the oracle to which these classes have been proven equal, call on that example, and be done--since there exists an oracle to which they have already been proven equal this is my proof that the inequality doesn't relativize?

Or do I have to apply oracles specifically to the machines in my proof of the inequality and see if it relativizes?

I'm confused about how proving relativization / non-relativization of a specific proof of some statement relates to the relativization of other proofs of the same statement.

How can I reference the fact that other proofs of a statement relativize / don't relativize to help me prove my own relativization result about my proof of that statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A proof relativizes if every step in the proof relativizes. You should go over your proof, and check whether each step remains valid in the presence of an oracle.

In contrast, a result relativizes *by definition* if it still holds relative to an arbitrary oracle. Hence, to show that a result doesn't relativize, all you have to do is give an oracle with respect to which it fails.

If we're interested in some specific statement, whose truth value we are not sure of, and there are both an oracle relative to which the statement holds and an oracle relative to which the statement doesn't hold, then we can conclude that no relativizing proof can either prove or refute the statement.

Comment: So, if my result is C != B. and someone else has a result that C^O = B^O relative to O, then this is all that is needed to say that the result C=!B does not relativize, all i need to do is cite the example that C^O = B^O and this proves my result C=! B does not relativize? Or are there more steps? Sorry this is what im confused about.

Comment: That's all you need to do.

Comment: @RingRing Let me add to this answer that we may indeed have the following situation: a non-relativizing proof of a result is found, and then later a relativizing proof is also found. A given result may have many very different proofs.

Comment: @NoahSchweber "So how can I reference the fact that other proofs of a statement relativize / don't relativize to help me prove my own relativization result about my proof of that statement?" This is the bottom paragraph in my question. How do I reconcile what you are saying with what Yuval is saying. You are saying relativization is a feature of the proof of a statement, not the statement. Yuval is seemingly saying the opposite that its a feature of the statement. the statement, not the proof, is what relativizes (is true or false with respect to certain oracles).

Comment: A proof can be relativizing, and a statement can be relativizing. If your prove a statement using a relativizing proof, then the statement is also relativizing.

Comment: okay sorry, so then how can i call on a result that C=B with respect to oracle O in order to show that my statement C!=B does not relativize (you said this is all i need to do in your first comment)? It would seem to me that it would be possible, based on what you are saying, that my result of C!=B could have been proven by a method that relativizes. If this is so then how does citing the existence of O, relative to which C = B, say that my proof doesn't relativize? sorry this is what I'm still confused about.

Comment: If your *proof* relativizes, then what you *prove* also relativizes. The opposite doesn't necessarily hold. You could prove a statement that happens to relativize using a non-relativizing proof. Your proof won't show that the statement relativizes.

Comment: @RingRing Adding to Yuval's comment: conversely, a non-relativizing proof won't show that the statement *doesn't* relativize. A non-relativizing proof simply doesn't give any information about whether the result in question relativizes or doesn't.

Comment: "If your proof relativizes, then what you prove also relativizes." So then because others have already shown that what was proved (the statement) does not relativize my proof is either wrong or cannot relativize.

Comment: Yes, that is the conclusion.

Comment: Yuval + @NoahSchweber sick, thank you !